# Elasticsearch: aggregate on a huge amount of data

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have an index with 10 million documents. I need a count of documents grouped by seconds. My query is like the following:

```
query = {
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "counts_per_second": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "interval": "second"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It always gets a timeout. Even if I run it on a  10k-document index, it takes 3 minutes. Is there any way to improve the performance of this query? I'm running it via elasticsearch-py btw.

Comment: Whats' the time span of those 10M documents? Are you sure you need to second by the second for the full timespan? Would it be ok to restrict to a given time span instead?

Comment: @Val: The time span is just 24 hours. They are server logs. Yes, I need second by second for the full timespan.

Comment: you realize that you're asking for 86400 buckets ? that's huge !!! Can you explain what your use case is?

Comment: @Val: I need to monitor number of API calls per second for my work. This is a key performance metric for us.

Comment: That's probably not the best way to do it. Is it for enforcing some kind of throttling?

Comment: Just to update, it turns out to be a hardware problem. Now the same code is running perfectly fine on a new ES cluster.